# Check if file is smaller than another file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a check in my backup script, so that if the new file to be backed up is smaller than my old backup I'll quit the script, to avoid backing up corrupted data.

But all the answers I find about this are about checking if a file is bigger/smaller than a bytes value instead of another file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stat` to get a file size. Use `-c` to specify a format and use `%s` as the format to get the file size in bytes.

```
#! /bin/bash

file=...
backup=...

file_size=$(stat -c %s "$file")
backup_size=$(stat -c %s "$backup")

if (( file_size > backup_size )) ; then
    echo "$file" is bigger.
fi
```

Comment: so it's not possible to just compare directly to another file?

Comment: @Freedo: Bash has `-ot` and `-nt` to say if a file is older/newer than another file, but it can't directly compare sizes. However, in Perl, `-s` returns the size of the file, so you can compare `if (-s $file1 < -s $file2)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use stat `stat --format=%s <file>` to get a size of the file
and then simply compare the integer values using built-in -gt and -eq
operators. Example file-smaller.sh can look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

file1_size="$(stat --format=%s file1)"
file2_size="$(stat --format=%s file2)"

if [ "$file1_size" -eq "$file2_size" ]
then
    printf "Files have equal sizes\n"
elif [ "$file1_size" -gt "$file2_size" ]
then
    printf "file1 is larger\n"
else
    printf "file2 is larger\n"
fi
```

Usage:

```
$ echo abc >> file1
$ echo abcd >> file2
$ ./file-smaller.sh
file2 is larger
$ cp file1 file2
$ ./file-smaller.sh
Files have equal size
```